# extract hypen separated values from a column and apply UDF

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a `dataframe` like as provided below:

```
+--------+-------+-------+--------------+--------------------+-----------------+----------+--------------------+------------+
|sequence|recType|valCode|registerNumber|                rest|        errorCode|errorType |    errorDescription|isSuccessful|
+--------+-------+-------+--------------+--------------------+-----------------+----------+--------------------+------------+
|       9|     11|      0|      XXXX2288|110XXXX2288MKKKKK...|         CHAR0088|     ERROR|Records out of se...|           N|
|       9|     12|      0|      XXXX2288|130XXXX22880011ZZ...|         CHAR0088|     ERROR|Records out of se...|           N|
|       9|     18|      0|      XXXX2288|140XXXX2288      ...|         CHAR0088|     ERROR|Records out of se...|           N|
+--------+-------+-------+--------------+--------------------+-----------------+----------+--------------------+------------+           N|
```

The below code uses `UDF` to populate the data for `errorType` and `errorDescription` columns.
The `UDFs` i.e. `resolveErrorTypeUDF` and `resolveErrorDescUDF` take one `errorCode` as input and provide the respective `errorType` and `errorDescription` in output respectively.

```
errorFinalDf = errorDfAll.na.fill("") \
 .withColumn("errorType", resolveErrorTypeUDF(col("errorCode"))) \
 .withColumn("errorDescription", resolveErrorDescUDF(col("errorCode"))) \
 .withColumn("isSuccessful", when(trim(col("errorCode")).eqNullSafe(""), "Y").otherwise("N")) \
 .dropDuplicates()
```

Please notice that, I used to get only one `error code` in `errorCode` column. Now onwards, I will be getting single/multiple `-` separated `error codes` in the `errorCode` column. And I need to populate all the mapping `errorType` and `errorDescription` and write them into respective column with `-` separation.

The new `dataframe` would look like this.

```
+--------+-------+-------+--------------+--------------------+-----------------+----------+--------------------+------------+
|sequence|recType|valCode|registerNumber|                rest|        errorCode|errorType |    errorDescription|isSuccessful|
+--------+-------+-------+--------------+--------------------+-----------------+----------+--------------------+------------+
|       7|      1|      0|      XXXX8822|010XXXX8822XBCDEF...|CHAR0009-CHAR0021|ERROR-WARN|Short Failed-Miss...|           N|
|       7|     11|      0|      XXXX8822|110XXXX8822LLLLLL...|CHAR0009-CHAR0021|ERROR-WARN|Short Failed-Miss...|           N|
|       7|     12|      0|      XXXX8822|120XXXX8822011GB ...|CHAR0009-CHAR0021|ERROR-WARN|Short Failed-Miss...|           N|
|       7|     18|      0|      XXXX8822|180XXXX8822      ...|CHAR0009-CHAR0021|ERROR-WARN|Short Failed-Miss...|           N|
|       7|     18|      0|      XXXX8822|180XXXX88220     ...|CHAR0009-CHAR0021|ERROR-WARN|Short Failed-Miss...|           N|
+--------+-------+-------+--------------+--------------------+-----------------+----------+--------------------+------------+
```

What changes would be needed to accommodate the new scenario. Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You need minimal changes, limited only to your `UDFs`.

Suppose you have a simple python function, `get_type_from_code` able to convert a string with the error code to the correspondent type (the same applies to the description).

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, types as T

def get_type_from_code(c: str) -> str:
    """Function to convert error code to error type.

    Mind the interface: string in, string out
    """
    return {'CHAR0009': 'ERROR', 'CHAR0021': 'WARNING'}.get(c, 'UNKNOWN')


@F.udf(returnType=T.StringType())
def convert_errcodes_to_types(codes: str) -> str:
    """Convert a string of error codes separated by '-' into a string of types concatenated with '-'"""
    return '-'.join(
        map(get_type_from_code, codes.split('-'))
    )
```

Done!